# jQuery, javascript, css , html. Как динамически добавить div еще с 2мя дивами

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
   
$('#next').click(function()
{
var key = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
var nam = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
var p1 = $('<div class ="m1">'+ key +'</div>');
var p2 = $('<div class ="m2">'+ nam +'</div>');
    $('<div class ="block"></div>').prependTo('#blocks');
   $(p1).attr('id', key).prependTo('.block');
    $(p2).attr('name', nam).prependTo('.block');
  
 });
```

```css
#blocks {
    float: left;
    }
.block {
    width: 600px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    }
.m1, .m2 {
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='next'>More</button>
<div id="blocks"></div>
```

Здравствуйте.
Никак не получается динамически добавить div еще с 2мя div
Динамически из базы получаю значения в key и nam и хочу добавлять с ними div, внутри которого div с значением key и div с значением nam

Я хочу, чтобы на одной строке добавлялся один див внутри с двумя дивами, у которых key и nam

Comment: Что значит `Никак не получается добавить` и `Все криво получается` ? Конкретика. Нужна конкретика.....

Comment: перед var что за фигня?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, конкретика : смотрите фрагмент кода лучше него не могу объяснить. Все друг на друга заезжает, мне кажется я со стилями что-то напутал.

Comment: @Jean-Claude поправил

Comment: @ОлегИванов  http://i.stack.imgur.com/afEhE.jpg ........баг с неизвестной проблемой не воспроизводится....а значит вопрос можно закрывать, как плохосформулированный, как не воспроизводится и прочее

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , я немного поправил, можно запустить теперь. Я хочу, чтобы на одной строке добавлялся один див внутри с двумя дивами, у которых key и nam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-то намудрили с `.prependTo()`. Сделайте проще: темплейт HTML кода, который будет вставляться. В нём специальные строки, которые ни с чем не спутать (`%KEY%`, `%NAM%`) – потом будем их заменять на значения.

По клику получаем значения, собираем готовый html взяв темплейт и заменив в нём спецстроки на значения, и вставляем этот код в начале содержимого нужного `div`'а:

```js
var tmpl = [
  '<div class="block">',
  '  <div class="m1" id="%KEY%">%KEY%</div>',
  '  <div class="m2" name="%NAM%">%NAM%</div>',
  '</div>'
].join("\n");
var el = document.getElementById('blocks');

function addMore() {
  var key = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
  var nam = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
  var html = tmpl
    .replace(/%KEY%/g, key)
    .replace(/%NAM%/g, nam)
  ;
  el.innerHTML = html + el.innerHTML;
}

$('#next').on('click', addMore);
```

```css
#blocks {
    float: left;
    }
.block {
    width: 600px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    }
.m1, .m2 {
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='next'>More</button>
<div id="blocks"></div>
```

---

P.S. код большого темплейта удобнее держать без кавычек и массива, обернув в тег `<script>`. Обратите внимание на `type="text/template"` – такой "скрипт" не выполнится, но его содержание можно потом получить:

```
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl-block">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="m1" id="%KEY%">%KEY%</div>
    <div class="m2" name="%NAM%">%NAM%</div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Получить его содержание в скрипте по `id`:

```
var tmpl = document.getElementById('tmpl-block').innerHTML;
```

Comment: а все же, c prependTo как это сделать и где я намудрил, на будущее хотел бы понять для себя

Comment: И еще как теперь мне обратиться к классу .block и вывести значение attr('id'), раньше так обращался,    $('#blocks').on('click', '.block', function() {
                           console.log($(this).attr('id')); });

Comment: с [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) вместо строки `el.innerHTML = html + el.innerHTML;` можно записать так: `$('#blocks').prepend(html);`

Comment: клик ловить по элементу с KEY, у него класс `m1`, примерно так: `$('#blocks').on('click', '.block .m1', function() { console.log($(this).attr('id')); });`